# C++: Trying to understand pass by reference to vectors

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference

I am learning  C++ and I don't really understand how to pass objects through functions. I read that there were three ways to do it. Passing by value,reference and pointer. I think I am trying to do by reference?

I am pretty sure I am having issues with passing by reference because I tried to test it in the main without calling functions by doing

```
std::string nameInput = "Penguin";
std::string colorInput = "Black";
Animal temp(nameInput,colorInput);
zoo.addAnimal(temp);
zoo.printDatabase();
```

And it works out fine. But when I try to call it through functions I am not even able to add it to the vector.Before posting this I tried addAnimal(Animal &toAdd) but I am not sure what is really going on. Because aren't I just passing in the address to the function? And not the object animal itself.

Or maybe I am totally looking at the wrong direction. Which is why I like posting here because having another set of eyes is always nice!

```
//Zoo.h

#include<vector>
#include<animal.h>

#ifndef ZOO_H_
#define ZOO_H_

class Zoo{
    private:
        std::vector<Animal> database;
    public:
        void addAnimal(animal toAdd);
        void printDatabase();
};

#endif ZOO_H_

//Animal.h

#include<string>

#ifndef ANIMAL_H_
#define ANIMAL_H_

class Animal{
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::string color;

    public:
        Animal(std::string name, std::string color);
        void printInfo();
}

#endif ANIMAL_H_


//Zoo methods
void Zoo::printDatabase(){
    for(std::vector<Animal>::iterator list = database.begin(); list != list.end(); list++){
        (*list).printInfo();
    }
}

void Zoo::addAnimal(Animal toAdd){
    database.push_back(toAdd);
}

//Animal Methods
Animal::Animal(std::string inputName, std::string inputColor){
    name = inputName;
    color = inputColor;
}

void Animal::printInfo(){
    std::cout << "Name: " << name << "\n";
    std::cout << "Color: " << color >> "\n";
}


//main.cpp
int main(){

    Zoo zoo;
    std::string input;
    do{
        printMenu();
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        if(!input.empty()){
            decide(input, zoo);
        }
    }while(input != "3";
}

void printMenu(){
    std::cout <<"Zoo database\n";
    std::cout << "1.Add  Animal \n";
    std::cout << "2.Print \n";
    std::cout << "3.Exit \n";
}

void decide(std::string input, Zoo zooInput){

    std::string name;
    std::string color;

    if(input == "1"){
        std::cout << "Please enter the name of the animal to add \n";
        std::getline(std::cin,name);
        std::cout << "Please enter the color of the animal \n";
        std::getline(std::cin,color);

        Animal temp(name,color);
        zooInput.addAnimal(temp);
    }

    if(input == "2"){
        zooInput.printDatabase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand what you're asking but in your decide function, you aren't passing by reference or pointer, but by value.

You want to pass the zoo by reference since you expect the function to modify the zoo passed to it, not make a copy of it and modify that.

Also, addAnimal is fine, because you do want to pass by value here. Not by reference or pointer, because the animal in the calling function is going to get destroyed later.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comment, you want to change your function's signature to:

```
void decide(std::string input, Zoo& zooInput){
```

In these lines here:

```
Animal temp(name,color);
zooInput.addAnimal(temp);
```

A copy of `temp` is passed to `addAnimal` and subsequently copied/moved into `zooInput`'s vector. Passing it by reference will make no difference because it is copied into the vector anyway.

However, because `zooInput` is passed by value, changes to it will not be reflected outside the function.

Comment: I honestly never would have suspected that the zoo was my problem. Thank you! If I had enough reputation to upvote I would!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this should not even compile...

1. You forgot to put `;` at the end of `Animal` class declaration.
2. In `main()` function, there is no closing `)` in while loop, here: `while(input != "3";`
3. Then you have methods like `void addAnimal(animal toAdd);` and `animal` is not declared anywhere, should have been `Animal`.
4. In your for loop, you have `for(std::vector<Animal>::iterator list = database.begin(); list != list.end(); list++){`. Obviously, `list` is an iterator and it does not have `end()` method, so `list != list.end()` is plain wrong.
5. In `std::cout << "Color: " << color >> "\n";`, you use `>> "\n"`, which is just wrong.
6. Using `std::getline(std::cin, input);` and then `if(!input.empty())` does not work. It could just get stuck in infinitive loop on `EOF`.

And finally, back to references. You pass `Zoo` by value (copy) into your `decide()` function. Therefore, it adds an animal into its own private copy of Zoo which is destroyed upon leaving the function scope. Therefore, `Zoo` object defined in `main()` is never modified. To fix it, change `void decide(std::string input, Zoo zooInput)` to `void decide(std::string input, Zoo& zooInput)`.

And here is your program, somewhat fixed:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Animal {
    std::string name;
    std::string color;

public:
    Animal(std::string name, std::string color);
    void printInfo();
};

class Zoo {
    std::vector<Animal> database;
public:
    void addAnimal(Animal toAdd);
    void printDatabase();
};

void Zoo::printDatabase(){
    for(std::vector<Animal>::iterator list = database.begin(); list != database.end(); list++){
        (*list).printInfo();
    }
}

void Zoo::addAnimal(Animal toAdd){
    database.push_back(toAdd);
}

Animal::Animal(std::string inputName, std::string inputColor){
    name = inputName;
    color = inputColor;
}

void Animal::printInfo(){
    std::cout << "Name: " << name << "\n";
    std::cout << "Color: " << color << "\n";
}

void printMenu(){
    std::cout <<"Zoo database\n";
    std::cout << "1.Add  Animal \n";
    std::cout << "2.Print \n";
    std::cout << "3.Exit \n";
}

void decide(std::string input, Zoo& zooInput) {
    std::string name;
    std::string color;

    if(input == "1"){
        std::cout << "Please enter the name of the animal to add \n";
        std::getline(std::cin,name);
        std::cout << "Please enter the color of the animal \n";
        std::getline(std::cin,color);

        Animal temp(name,color);
        zooInput.addAnimal(temp);
    }

    if(input == "2"){
        zooInput.printDatabase();
    }
}

int main() {
    Zoo zoo;
    std::string input;
    printMenu();
    while (std::getline(std::cin, input)) {
        decide(input, zoo);
        if (input == "3")
            break;
        printMenu();
    }
}
```

Example run:

```
$ g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -o test ./test.cc  && ./test 
Zoo database
1.Add  Animal 
2.Print 
3.Exit 
1
Please enter the name of the animal to add 
cow
Please enter the color of the animal 
blue
Zoo database
1.Add  Animal 
2.Print 
3.Exit 
2
Name: cow
Color: blue
Zoo database
1.Add  Animal 
2.Print 
3.Exit 
1
Please enter the name of the animal to add 
lobster
Please enter the color of the animal 
green
Zoo database
1.Add  Animal 
2.Print 
3.Exit 
2
Name: cow
Color: blue
Name: lobster
Color: green
Zoo database
1.Add  Animal 
2.Print 
3.Exit 
3
$
```

Comment: I don't think it's proper to solve and hand over homework on SO.

Comment: @Al-Muhandis: Sorry, I never been to college so I don't know how to distinguish a homework from a programming problem of a man who learns C++.

Comment: @Al-Muhandis He said he's learning C++. Typically when I read that, I don't think "homework" but a beginner who's self-taught. That's just me though. The problem was instantly noticeable off the bat, so there was no need to fix the rest of the program.

Comment: A program about adding animals to zoos is very suspicious of an assignment. Given such a suspicion, from what I've seen so far on SO, the preferable practice is to avoid solving and re-posting the code.

Comment: Oh nevermind. I think you mean that it has to be zoo.end(). Haha thank you. Also thank you for the rigorous breakdown of my code. It was actually a example I had to type up instead of copy  pasting my actually "assignment persay" because yes the problem was for homework but I didn't want to come off as stuck on homework please solve for me.